# Unable to apply Pascal Casing to Swagger output

Tags: azure-functions, openapi

I've added OpenAPI to my .Net8 isolated http trigger Azure Function using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi 1.5.1

This is my hostbuilder code:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    //.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => worker.UseNewtonsoftJson())    
    .ConfigureOpenApi()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddOptions<AzureFunctionAppSettings>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, config) =>
        {
            config.Bind(settings);
        });
    })
    .Build();
```

Yet all my class and property names are still in CamelCase in the generated Swagger html. I tried changing the hostbuilder code to activate PascalCasing, but that did not work.

how can I activate PascalCasing?

Answer (score 0):

To convert Swagger Output of Isolated Azure functions to Pascal case, you need to set the *PropertyNamingPolicy* to *null*.

**Program.cs:**

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => worker.UseNewtonsoftJson())
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            options.SerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
            options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
            options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());          
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

To specifically force the Swagger output to Pascal case:

- create a `NamingStrategy` class to have that logic and assign it.
- customize property names and values with `System.Text.Json`.

Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0#use-a-custom-json-property-naming-policy) to customize properties in the required property naming policy.

**References:**

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused since I4m using NewtonSoft for serialisations.
My classes & properties are Pascal cased, so I do not need to use [JsonPropertyName] I assume.
I've added your code to my hostbuilder, still camelCase results :-(